# Before_validation: updating and maintaining continuity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, datatable

I have a simple work schedule rails app. The jobs in the schedule will be ordered by the priority of the job. Since some jobs may change in priority, and by the same nature, order they need to be completed, i need to be able to update the priority and the priority of the rest of the table to ensure no 2 jobs share the same priority. Once the priority is updated, i want it to make that the list of priorities is continuous, in other words, the priorities are labeled 1,2,3,4,5,etc. instead of having gaps like 1,2,4,5,6,8,etc.

Can someone help me figure out the proper coding to achieve this?

This is what i currently have in my model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Dirty
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :job_items

  before_validation :update_priorities

  validates :priority, :uniqueness => true

  private

  def update_priorities
  if self.priority_changed?
    self.class.where("priority >= ?", self.priority).update_all("priority = priority + 1")
  else
    nil  
  end
end
```

The above code updates the priorities fine if its a brand new job. However, once i start to re-order the current jobs, gaps begin to appear in the sequence.

I am currently using Rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the acts_as_list provided by Veraticus, but it just wasn't working properly for my application. After some fiddling with it, i changed my code to the following and it works just like i need it to.

```
  def update_priorities
if self.priority_changed?
  if self.priority < self.priority_was
    self.class.where("priority >= ?", self.priority).update_all("priority = priority + 1")
    self.class.where("priority > ?", self.priority_was).update_all("priority = priority - 1")
  else
    nil
  end
  if self.priority > self.priority_was
    self.class.where("priority <= ?", self.priority).update_all("priority = priority - 1")
    self.class.where("priority < ?", self.priority_was).update_all("priority = priority + 1")
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for here is [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list), which will automatically do this sort of thing for you. For example, if you're creating a new job and you want a certain position for it:

```
@job = Job.create
@job.insert_at(2) # will automatically insert your job at position 2, moving all other items in the list according.
```

To see all the methods acts_as_list provides you, [check out the comments in the source](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/lib/acts_as_list/active_record/acts/list.rb).

Comment: It might be. Looking at the code and example they use in the commented out code, it seems like i need a master class to wrap around the jobs. If thats true, then it wont work for me.

Comment: I think you can use it without a wrapping class by not providing a scope. So just call ```acts_as_list :column => 'priority``` in the model and it should provide all the acts_as_list magic without needing a scope.

Comment: I could be wrong but i think it does require the master class. I don't think it knows how to adjust the rest of the jobs without referring to the master class.